# How to use systemd after with services that uses @

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to make my systemd service start AFTER wireguard but I don't know how to do that because wireguard uses that systemd @ format.

```
find /etc -name *wg-quick*                                                                                                                                                                                               
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/wg-quick@wg0.service
```

What do I use in my after section of systemd?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start your service after the wg-quick@wg0.service, use:

```
[Unit]
...
After=wg-quick@wg0.service
...
```

in your unit file.